# Jointjs petri-net graph tokens do not render! What can i do?

Tags: typescript, token, render, jointjs, petri-net

currently I am trying to set up a Petrinet generator as jupyter widget. Therefore I am using the cookiecutter-ts-widget template, which means i am implementing the frontend logics in typescript. I am happy with the progress and everything works fine except the tokens of my places are not rendered.

Here is how I am creating an Example on the `joint.dia.Paper`:

```
PetriView.graph = new joint.dia.Graph();
PetriView.pn = joint.shapes.pn;
PetriView.paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
      el: document.createElement("div"),
      width: this.width,
      height: this.height,
      gridSize: PetriView.gridSize,
      defaultAnchor: { name: 'perpendicular' },
      defaultConnectionPoint: { name: 'boundary' },
      model: PetriView.graph,
      linkPinning: false,                             // prevent dangling links
      interactive: function() { return true },        // make cells draggable
    });

private firstExample() {
    this.clearAll();

    // Define Places
    var pReady = new PetriView.pn.Place({
        position: { x: 140, y: 50 },
        attrs: {
            '.label': {
                'text': 'ready',
                'fill': '#7c68fc' },
            '.root': {
                'stroke': '#7c68fc',
                'stroke-width': 3,
            },
            '.alot > text': {
                'fill': '#fe854c',
                'font-family': 'Courier New',
                'font-size': 20,
                'font-weight': 'bold',
                'ref-x': 0.5,
                'ref-y': 0.5,
                'y-alignment': -0.5,
                'transform': null as any
            },
            '.tokens > circle': {
                'fill': '#7a7e9b'
            }
        },
        'tokens': 1,
    });

    var pIdle = pReady.clone()
        .attr('.label/text', 'idle')
        .position(140, 260)
        .set('tokens', 2);

    *[...]*

    // Define Transitions
    var tProduce = new PetriView.pn.Transition({
        size: { width: 30, height: 40 },
        position: { x: 50, y: 160 },
        attrs: {
            '.label': {
                'text': 'produce',
                'fill': '#fe854f'
            },
            '.root': {
                'fill': '#9586fd',
                'stroke': '#7c68fc'
            },
            'rect': {
                width: 12,
                height: 50,
                fill: '#000000',
                stroke: '#000000',
                "stroke-width": 3,
            },
        }
    });

    var tSend = tProduce.clone()
        .attr('.label/text', 'send')
        .position(270, 160);

    *[...]*

    // add cells to graph and create links
    PetriView.graph.addCell([pReady, pIdle, buffer, cAccepted, cReady, tProduce, tSend, tAccept, tConsume]);
    PetriView.graph.addCell([
      PetriView.link(tProduce, pReady), PetriView.link(pReady, tSend), PetriView.link(tSend, pIdle), PetriView.link(pIdle, tProduce), 
      PetriView.link(tSend, buffer), PetriView.link(buffer, tAccept), PetriView.link(tAccept, cAccepted), 
      PetriView.link(cAccepted, tConsume), PetriView.link(tConsume, cReady), PetriView.link(cReady, tAccept)
    ]);

    return PetriView.graph
  }
```

By console-logging you can see that the tokens are in the respective cells (e.g. tokens: 1) but are not rendered even though the whole graph is rendered perfectly fine.
Further i noticed that the `pn.Place` cells only contain the following flags:
`{PORTS: 16, RENDER: 64, RESIZE: 8, ROTATE: 32, TOOLS: 4, TRANSLATE: 2, UPDATE: 1}`

According to my understanding there should be a `TOKENS` flag as well, which is checked on and finally tokens are added in the background in form of dynamic HTML.

A correct example of a Cell containing tokens:

```
  <circle class="root" id="v-8" r="25" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#7c68fc"   transform="translate(25, 25)" stroke-width="3"></circle>
  <g class="tokens two">
    <circle id="v-10" fill="#7a7e9b" r="5" transform="translate(19, 25)"></circle>
    <circle id="v-11" fill="#7a7e9b" r="5" transform="translate(31, 25)"></circle>
  </g>
```

versus my cell (containing non rendered tokens):

```
<circle class="root" id="v-7" r="25" fill="#ffffff" stroke="red" transform="translate(25, 25)" stroke-width="3"></circle>
<g class="tokens"></g>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the initializer of a new Place (i.e. `new pn.Place()`) to add a `TOKENS`-flag internally?
Or alternatively do you know how i could add this flag myself?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after posting this question on their GitHub i received an answer which turned out to be the solution. You need to specify the cellNamespace for the graph and the cellViewNamespace for the paper object.

See here: https://github.com/clientIO/joint/issues/1579

```
const namespace = joint.shapes; // e.g. { standard: { Rectangle: RectangleElementClass }}
const graph = new joint.dia.Graph({ /* attributes of the graph */ }, { cellNamespace: namespace });
const paper = new joint.dia.Paper({ cellViewNamespace: namespace });
```

As kumilingus pointed out, this should be fixed with release of jointjs v4 by making the namespace mandatory.